# Applying custom function to each row uses only first value of argument

Tags: r, apply, na, missing-data

I am trying to recode `NA` values to `0` in a subset of columns using the following dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:10),
  trials = sample(1:3, 10, replace = T),
  t1 = c(sample(c(1:9, NA), 10)),
  t2 = c(sample(c(1:7, rep(NA, 3)), 10)),
  t3 = c(sample(c(1:5, rep(NA, 5)), 10))
  )
```

Each row has a certain number of trials associated with it (between 1-3), specified by the `trials` column. columns `t1-t3` represent scores for each trial.

The number of trials indicates the subset of columns in which `NA`s should be recoded to `0`: `NA`s that are within the number of trials represent missing data, and should be recoded as `0`, while `NA`s outside the number of trials are not meaningful, and should remain `NA`s. So, for a row where `trials == 3`, an `NA` in column `t3` would be recoded as `0`, but in a row where `trials == 2`, an `NA` in `t3` would remain an `NA`.

So, I tried using this function:

```
replace0 <- function(x, num.sun) {
  x[which(is.na(x[1:(num.sun + 2)]))] <- 0
  return(x)
}
```

This works well for single vectors. When I try applying the same function to a data frame with `apply()`, though:

```
apply(df, 1, replace0, num.sun = df$trials)
```

I get a warning saying:

```
In 1:(num.sun + 2) :
  numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used
```

The result is that instead of having the value of `num.sun` change every row according to the value in `trials`, `apply()` simply uses the first value in the `trials` column for every single row. How could I apply the function so that the `num.sun` argument changes according to the value of `df$trials`?

Thanks!

**Edit:** as some have commented, the original example data had some non-NA scores that didn't make sense according to the trials column. Here's a corrected dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:5),
  trials = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 1), rep(3, 2)),
  t1 = c(NA, 7, NA, 6, NA),
  t2 = c(NA, NA, 3, 7, 12),
  t3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 4, NA)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

```
# create an index of the NA values
w <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)

# create an index with the max column by row where an NA is allowed to be replaced by a zero
m <- matrix(c(1:nrow(df), (df$trials + 2)), ncol = 2)

# subset 'w' such that only the NA's which fall in the scope of 'm' remain
i <- w[w[,2] <= m[,2][match(w[,1], m[,1])],]

# use 'i' to replace the allowed NA's with a zero
df[i] <- 0
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    id trials t1 t2 t3
> 1   1      1  3 NA  5
> 2   2      2  2  2 NA
> 3   3      2  6  6  4
> 4   4      3  0  1  2
> 5   5      1  5 NA NA
> 6   6      3  7  0  0
> 7   7      3  8  7  0
> 8   8      2  4  5  1
> 9   9      2  1  3 NA
> 10 10      1  9  4  3
> ```

You could easily wrap this in a function:

```
replace.NA.with.0 <- function(df) {
  w <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)
  m <- matrix(c(1:nrow(df), (df$trials + 2)), ncol = 2)
  i <- w[w[,2] <= m[,2][match(w[,1], m[,1])],]
  df[i] <- 0
  return(df)
}
```

Now, using `replace.NA.with.0(df)` will produce the above result.

---

As noted by others, some rows (1, 3 & 10) have more values than trails. You could tackle that problem by rewriting the above function to:

```
replace.with.NA.or.0 <- function(df) {
  w <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)
  df[w] <- 0

  v <- tapply(m[,2], m[,1], FUN = function(x) tail(x:5,-1))
  ina <- matrix(as.integer(unlist(stack(v)[2:1])), ncol = 2)
  df[ina] <- NA

  return(df)
}
```

Now, using `replace.with.NA.or.0(df)` produces the following result:

> ```
>    id trials t1 t2 t3
> 1   1      1  3 NA NA
> 2   2      2  2  2 NA
> 3   3      2  6  6 NA
> 4   4      3  0  1  2
> 5   5      1  5 NA NA
> 6   6      3  7  0  0
> 7   7      3  8  7  0
> 8   8      2  4  5 NA
> 9   9      2  1  3 NA
> 10 10      1  9 NA NA
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
x <- is.na(df)
df[x & t(apply(x, 1, cumsum)) > 3 - df$trials] <- 0
```

The output looks like this:

```
> df
   id trials t1 t2 t3
1   1      1  3 NA  5
2   2      2  2  2 NA
3   3      2  6  6  4
4   4      3  0  1  2
5   5      1  5 NA NA
6   6      3  7  0  0
7   7      3  8  7  0
8   8      2  4  5  1
9   9      2  1  3 NA
10 10      1  9  4  3
> x <- is.na(df)
> df[x & t(apply(x, 1, cumsum)) > 3 - df$trials] <- 0
> df
   id trials t1 t2 t3
1   1      1  3 NA  5
2   2      2  2  2 NA
3   3      2  6  6  4
4   4      3  0  1  2
5   5      1  5 NA NA
6   6      3  7  0  0
7   7      3  8  7  0
8   8      2  4  5  1
9   9      2  1  3 NA
10 10      1  9  4  3
```

Note: row 1/3/10, is problematic since there are more non-NA values than the trials.

Comment: rows 3 and 10 as well are problematic

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, thanks for the note. I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Here I just rewrite your function using double subsetting `x[paste0('t',x['trials'])]`, which overcome the problem in the other two solutions with **row 6**

```
replace0 <- function(x){
         #browser()
         x_na <- x[paste0('t',x['trials'])]
         if(is.na(x_na)){x[paste0('t',x['trials'])] <- 0}
     return(x)
}

t(apply(df, 1, replace0))

     id trials t1 t2 t3
[1,]  1      1  3 NA  5
[2,]  2      2  2  2 NA
[3,]  3      2  6  6  4
[4,]  4      3 NA  1  2
[5,]  5      1  5 NA NA
[6,]  6      3  7 NA  0
[7,]  7      3  8  7  0
[8,]  8      2  4  5  1
[9,]  9      2  1  3 NA
[10,] 10      1  9  4  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` way, note that it doesn't give the same output as other solutions.

Your example data shows results for trials that "didn't happen", I assumed your real data doesn't.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  nest(matches("^t\\d")) %>%
  mutate(data = map2(data,trials,~mutate_all(.,replace_na,0) %>% select(.,1:.y))) %>%
  unnest

#    id trials t1 t2 t3
# 1   1      1  3 NA NA
# 2   2      2  2  2 NA
# 3   3      2  6  6 NA
# 4   4      3  0  1  2
# 5   5      1  5 NA NA
# 6   6      3  7  0  0
# 7   7      3  8  7  0
# 8   8      2  4  5 NA
# 9   9      2  1  3 NA
# 10 10      1  9 NA NA
```

Using the more commonly used `gather` strategy this would be:

```
df %>%
  gather(k,v,matches("^t\\d")) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(1:first(trials)) %>%
  mutate_at("v",~replace(.,is.na(.),0)) %>%
  spread(k,v)

# # A tibble: 10 x 5
# # Groups:   id [10]
#       id trials    t1    t2    t3
#    <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1      1     3    NA    NA
#  2     2      2     2     2    NA
#  3     3      2     6     6    NA
#  4     4      3     0     1     2
#  5     5      1     5    NA    NA
#  6     6      3     7     0     0
#  7     7      3     8     7     0
#  8     8      2     4     5    NA
#  9     9      2     1     3    NA
# 10    10      1     9    NA    NA
```